# Server Script calling an external source returns object error

Tags: google-app-maker

I am attempting to convert an app I built in Google Forms + App Script to an App Maker app. This app interacts with Pagerduty via API. It will eventually edit the contact info for agents in Pagerduty, but this proof of concept I built should just be getting an agent's contact info.

I keep getting an error when I'm attempting to add the headers and options to the URL in the same way I did in Apps Script.

Error: Exception: Invalid argument: https://api.pagerduty.com/users/PBQHZKE/contact_methods/P6Q90HR[object%20Object] at getPagerDutyContactInfo (ServerScript:21)

I think I've got the wrong type of object after the URL, but I've been unable to find documentation on what this should be. At this point I am not looking for any help with the Pagerduty API. I just can't figure out how to correctly add the parameters onto the end of the URL in App Maker.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```js
function getPagerDutyContactInfo() {
  var headers = {
    "Accept": "application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2",
    "Authorization": "Token token=<API KEY>",
  };
  var options =
    {
    "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
    "contentType" : "application/json",
    "method" : "get",
    "headers" : headers
//    "payload" : infoPD
  };
  console.log("test-gr");
  
  // Line below returns this error: Exception: Invalid argument: https://api.pagerduty.com/users/PBQHZKE/contact_methods/P6Q90HR[object%20Object] at getPagerDutyContactInfo (ServerScript:21)
  var url = "https://api.pagerduty.com/users/PBQHZKE/contact_methods/P6Q90HR" + options;
  console.log("after var URL, before fetch");
  // The line below returns a 404 error from Pagerduty
  // var url = "https://api.pagerduty.com/users/PBQHZKE/contact_methods/P6Q90HR";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  console.log("after fetch");
  return response.getContentText();
}
```

Comment: Although I don't have experience with the Pagerduty API the only thing I notice that might give you the error is the comma after "headers": headers. This might be the case because you commented out the "payload" info but the options may still be looking for an additional argument after that comma. Like I said not sure if that is the cause of your error or not.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa Thanks for that suggestion. I did remove that comma, tested, and I still see the same error. I was really hoping it was that easy, lol.

Answer (score 0):

I consulted with a co-worker and he pointed out my error in the Java Script. I was trying to add my header info in the options variable to the end of the URL variable. Google's UrlFetchApp expects these after a comma on the UrlFetchApp call itself.

The code below now works. :)

```js
function getPagerDutyContactInfo() {
  var headers = {
    "Accept": "application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2",
    "Authorization": "Token token=<API KEY>",
  };
  var options =
    {
    "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
    "contentType" : "application/json",
    "method" : "get",
    "headers" : headers
//    "payload" : infoPD
  };
  console.log("test-gr");
  
  // Line below returns this error: Exception: Invalid argument: https://api.pagerduty.com/users/PBQHZKE/contact_methods/P6Q90HR[object%20Object] at getPagerDutyContactInfo (ServerScript:21)
  var url = "https://api.pagerduty.com/users/PBQHZKE/contact_methods/P6Q90HR";
  console.log("after var URL, before fetch");
  // The line below returns a 404 error from Pagerduty
  // var url = "https://api.pagerduty.com/users/PBQHZKE/contact_methods/P6Q90HR";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  console.log("after fetch");
  return response.getContentText();
}
```